# Perl script for creating two arrays

Tags: perl

Input: A list of numbers on command line

Output: Two lists of numbers ,one with input numbers that are greater than zero and one with those that are less than zero (Ignoring zero valued numbers)

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$i++ = 0;
$j++ = 0;

while ($number = <>)
 {
        if($number<0)
          $first[$i++]=$number;
        else
          $second[$j++]=$number;

 }

 print "The numbers with value less than zero are\n";

  foreach $number (@first)
     print $number;
print "The numbers with value greater than zero are\n"

  foreach $number(@second)
     print $number;
```

I am getting the following silly errors which i am not able to rectify.The errors are

```
divide.pl: 2: ++: not found
divide.pl: 3: ++: not found
divide.pl: 5: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Can anybody help me out with rectifying these errors please? I am new to perl script

Comment: You're not quite clear on whether you want to read the numbers from command line arguments (i.e. `./test.pl 1 2 3 4`) or from files given on the command line (what your code currently does), using standard input if no files are given.

Comment: i want to give the numbers as input from command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you present will hardly compile. Loops should have `{}` around the main block, arrays are better created with `push` (or `unshift`), you should use strict and warnings, and you can't do increments at the same time as assignments (e.g. `$i++ = 0`).

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@first, @second);

while (<STDIN>) {  # <STDIN> clearer than <> in this case
    chomp;
    if ($_ < 0) {
        push @first, $_;
    } elsif ($_ > 0) {
        push @second, $_;
    }
}

say "Numbers less than zero:";
say "@first";
say "Numbers greater than zero:";
say "@second";
```

Comment: how can i do this thru command line? lik ./divide.pl -1 1 2 3 4

Comment: Replace `while (<STDIN>)` with `for (@ARGV)`. And if you do that, you can remove `chomp`.

Comment: thanks a lot. This post helped me achieving what i needed. :)

Comment: @gogo You might also consider using `while(<>)` and using a file with the appropriate numbers, separated by newline. This will also work with STDIN if you do not supply arguments to the perl script.

Comment: @gogo Oh, just noticed you want to ignore zero values. Then you need to do `elsif ($_ > 0)` instead of `else`. Because otherwise `else` implicitly means `elsif ($_ >= 0)`.

Comment: yeah i just did that.Thank you once again.Nice place for beginners to start learning here.

Comment: @gogo Btw, if you feel this is the correct answer to your question, it would be proper form to mark it as such by clicking the check mark to the left.

Comment: one more thing i wanted to ask is,hw to check whether an array has elements filled or not? Here in my example,if no negative numbers are provided at command line,i shud display saying there are no negative numbers

Comment: You can do `say @array ? "@array" : "none"`.

Answer (score 6):

Curly braces on compound statements are not optional in Perl.

Your statements:

```
$i++=0;
$j++=0;
```

don't make sense; you probably just want to delete the "++".

You're missing a semicolon on one of your print statements.

Once you've got those problems fixed, you should add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

after the `#!` line.  This will introduce more error messages; you'll need to fix those as well.  For example, you'll need to declare your variables using `my()`.

Comment: but its not identifying "use". Giving an error saying use not found

Comment: "Giving an error saying use not found" is not any perl error text I am familiar with. Perhaps you should do an exact quote instead of a paraphrase.

Comment: Did you add the "use" on the same line as the `#!`?  Don't do that.  Line 1: `#!/usr/bin/perl`.  Line 2: `use strict;`.  Line 3: `use warnings;`.  (I usually have a blank line after the `#!`, but that doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `$i++ = 0` is supposed to mean, but change that to `$i = 0` to initialize the variables.

Also, the first thing yuu should do in the while loop is call `chomp($number)` to remove spurious newlines - `5\n` is not a number and treating it as one will confuse perl.

Once you've fixed that, post any new errors that show up - I don't see any other problems though.

Comment: divide.pl: 2: =: not found
divide.pl: 3: =: not found
I am getting these errors nw and also the syntax error of ")"

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing this perl script? Beyond the errors mentioned about the code itself. It looks like you are attempting to evaluate the code using `dash` instead of `perl`.

The errors you should be seeing if you were executing it with Perl would be like:

> Can't modify postincrement (++) in scalar assignment at /tmp/foo.pl
>   line 2, near "0;"

But instead, your errors are more in line with what `dash` outputs:

> $ dash /tmp/foo.pl
>
> /tmp/foo.pl: 2: ++: not found
>
> /tmp/foo.pl: 3: ++: not found

Once you've verified that you are running your perl script properly you can start working through the other problems people have mentioned your code. The easiest way to do this is to run it via `perl divide.pl` instead of whatever you are doing.